# I have error in my code, which is for passing aduio url (Retrieved from Firebase) from a adapter class to a fragment

Tags: java, android, xml, firebase

[image]Here is the code in which error exists...

What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be mixing method parameter concepts. You don't need to declare a variable type when invoking a method ie: `new string();`

This is typically done for defining the function `adapter MyAdaptor(string input){}`
Simply removing the type definition will change `options` from a parameter to a variable

```
 new recyclerViewAdapter(options);
```

Just ensure that your "options" are **declared** and **defined** before trying to use it.

**Definition**

Creating a new FirebaseRecyclerOptions typically follows this structure

```
 FirebaseRecyclerOptions<model> options =
                new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<model>()
                        .setQuery(query, model.class)
                        .build();
```

Source: https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/database/README.md

Comment: Bro check the updated question. about that were you saying, 
still it is showing error

Comment: My answer is still valid, I said specifically: declared && **defined** - you have not defined the value for options, it is null.